# Regular Expression Help

Tags: regex

The following regular expression is in use to validate email addresses:

```
^(([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$
```

I need to modify it to allow apostrophes in the username (before the @ symbol).

Comment: So what have you done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the apostrophe in each of the character classes you'd like it to appear, before the `@` symbol. If it's valid for the apostrophe to appear anywhere before the `@` symbol, then change the expression to:

```
^(([A-Za-z0-9']+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9']+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9']+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9']+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9']+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$
```

Note the added `'` characters inside the `[...]` classes before the `@` symbol.